# sh ow different PDF based on URL param

Tags: pdf

I have a  WP post that displays information based on a URL param from this post:

https://cascoly-images.com/prints-products/

this works fine for creating the links i need - eg choose 'Rainier' and

https://cascoly-images.com/cascoly-products-by-topic/?topic=Rainier

shows Rainier images . it currently also shows a hard-coded PDF but i need to be able to select a PDF based on 'topic' as these PDF are used elsewhere

I'm using a shortcode to retrieve the 'topic' param, but can't see a way to load a varying PDF.

*[https://cascoly.com/FAAimages/FAA-[urlparam](https://cascoly.com/FAAimages/FAA-%5Burlparam) param="topic"/].pdf*

throws a 404, but this works fine externally:

*https://cascoly.com/FAAimages/FAA-rainier.pdf*

aleternately, can i use a switch() w/in WP based on topic?